# Can I use Google Calendar API v3 to access someone else's public calendar without auth?

Tags: google-calendar-api

If someone has shared their Google calendar (for example, with a widget that displays it on a web page), then I can get the calendarID, e.g: p75ig3ni1smg4267qg0j0nhodc@group.calendar.google.com

I want to write an Alexa App (in NodeJS) to provide information from that calendar.  (I'm using this sample as a model: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/nodejs).

I have two questions:

1) Can I access it in the Google API without asking the owner of the calendar to perform some steps

2) Since the calendar is public, do I have to be authenticated in the API to access it? The above example assumes you need to authenticate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q1) Can I access it in the Google API without asking the owner of the calendar to perform some steps?

- A1. Yes. When the owner of the calendar shares calendars, other users can access the calendar using Google Calendar API
  . At that time, the owner is not required to do something.

> Q2) Since the calendar is public, do I have to be authenticated in the API to access it?

- A2. Yes. When users, who are not owner, know the ID of shared calendar, the users can access to the ID by authorizing for each account. Each user can use by the authorization process used at the Quickstart script.

  - You can test about this using [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/get). When you put the ID of other user's calendar, if the calendar is shared, you can access to it.

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, that test worked.  I had earlier tried similar list events: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list - and it said not found, but this time it worked.  It might have been using an URL encoded id before.   I have an error in the NodeJS, but I'll ask that tomorrow in a different question.

Comment: There's no simple URL query that will return the events without doing the auth then?

Comment: @NealWalters I'm glad your problem was solved. When you posted the next question, also I would like to confirm it. About simple URL, you can access using ``https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=#####``. ``eid`` can be retrieved by [calendar.events.get](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/get).

Comment: If I try to list events with a URL query : https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/p75ig3ni1smg4267qg0j0nhodc%40group.calendar.google.com/events I get "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",

Comment: Posted my API auth/redirect array issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47514590/google-oauth-cannot-read-property-0-of-undefined-at-authorize

Comment: @NealWalters I'm sorry for the inconvenience. ``https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/p75ig3ni1smg4267qg0j0nhodc%40group.calendar.google.com/events`` is API. So login is required. But after the eid is retrieved from the API, users can use the URL with the eid without login.