# Google OAuth - Cannot read property '0' of undefined at authorize

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to use the Google API to access someone else's public calendar.

My Code - taken from this page: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/nodejs

```
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  var clientSecret = credentials.installed.client_secret;
  var clientId = credentials.installed.client_id;
  console.log ("credentials.installed=" + 
            JSON.stringify(credentials.installed));

  var redirectUrl = credentials.installed.redirect_uris[0];
  var auth = new googleAuth();
  var oauth2Client = new auth.OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);
```

Error and console output (values of JSON changed for security):

```
    λ node testGoogleCalendarAPI.js
credentials.installed={"client_id":"123412341234-whatever.apps.googleusercontent.com","project_id":"app-name-187323","auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth","token_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token","auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs","client_secret":"whatever"}

    E:\GitHub\NealWalters\RabbiJoseph\testGoogleCalendarAPI.js:62
      var redirectUrl = credentials.installed.redirect_uris[0];
                                                           ^

    TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
        at authorize (E:\GitHub\NealWalters\RabbiJoseph\testGoogleCalendarAPI.js:62:56)
        at processClientSecrets (E:\GitHub\NealWalters\RabbiJoseph\testGoogleCalendarAPI.js:49:3)
        at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:447:3)
```

The JSON above comes from a file that I downloaded (and saved as 'client_secret.json') after running the steps on the above referenced URL. So why are the redirect URLs missing? Maybe that's something I left out when I ran that setup?  Further, the instructions were implying that I was setting up an API for my own calendar, where as I want to do an API to read someone else's calendar. They have it displayed in on a web page, so it is public. (See related question I posted: [Can I use Google Calendar API v3 to access someone else's public calendar without auth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47502314/can-i-use-google-calendar-api-v3-to-access-someone-elses-public-calendar-withou/47502537?noredirect=1#comment81961570_47502537))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you retrieve `client_secret.json` as following and try to run the script, again?

1. Click "Create credentials" as OAuth client ID.
2. Check "Other".

   - By this, the redirect url is automatically set. The url can be used for Quickstart.
3. Input Name.
4. Click "Create".
5. Click "OK".
6. Download JSON.
7. Rename JSON file to `client_secret.json`.

#### Note :

Before you run the script using new `client_secret.json`, please remove the existing `calendar-nodejs-quickstart.json`. When the default Quickstart is used, the file is created in `.credentials` of homedirectory.

If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see response until today.  Worked!  I didn't have to do the "NOTE:" part, couldn't find any calendar-nodejs-quickstart-.json.  It gave me a URL and then I had to paste in the code from that web page.  I had used "Website" before instead of "Other", would that make the difference?

Comment: It's reading my calendar, now I will try to figure out how to point it to the other public calendar.

Comment: @NealWalters "Other" has 2 redirect uris of ``"urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob","http://localhost"`` at the initial stage. And Quickstart can use them. So I thought that users are easy to use this mode. At the webapp, users have to set the redirect uri. I thought this might lead to the reason of errors.