# why a service account can't access a public shared calendar for listing events?

Tags: google-api, deno, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm using deno and https://googleapis.deno.dev/ to try to get some events from a publicly shared calendar.

Basically, this is the code:

```
import { Calendar, auth } from "https://googleapis.deno.dev/v1/calendar:v3.ts";

const serviceAccountConfig = await Deno.readTextFile(Deno.env.get('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'));

const credentials = auth.fromJSON(JSON.parse(serviceAccountConfig));
const calendar = new Calendar(credentials);

const cal = await calendar.eventsGet('<my-public-calendar-id-here>');
console.log(cal);
```

but this is what I get:

```
error: Uncaught (in promise) GoogleApiError: 401: Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.
      throw new GoogleApiError(
            ^
    at request (https://googleapis.deno.dev/_/base@v1/mod.ts:27:13)
    at eventLoopTick (ext:core/01_core.js:183:11)
    at async Calendar.eventsGet (https://googleapis.deno.dev/v1/calendar:v3.ts:476:18)
```

I've tried to check if some calendar privilege is needed for the google service account I use, but I haven't found any. Plus, this code is supposed to run on a backend, so I guess I should use a service account, not a user token (and keep in mind what I want to get has public access). Any piece of suggestion?

Comment: service accounts only work with calendar if its a google workspace account and domain wide deligation has been configured.

Comment: I see. And is it possible getting a public calendar infos from a server without any user authentication?

Comment: if its public just use an api key.

Comment: but that's not what https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47502314/can-i-use-google-calendar-api-v3-to-access-someone-elses-public-calendar-withou#47502537 says "es. When users, who are not owner, know the ID of shared calendar, the users can access to the ID by authorizing for each account"

Comment: That question is from 2017,  Im not sure when they locked down service accounts exactly but it was around then.   Service accounts only work with google calendar if you have them configured with domain wide delegation.    WHy do you want to use a service account?

Answer (score 0):

- You are not building the service object correctly.
- That's not a valid calendar id.
- You are not building the proper authorization credentials.

My code.

```
   // npm install googleapis@105 @google-cloud/local-auth@2.1.0 --save
// npm install googleapis

const {google} = require('googleapis');

// If modifying these scopes, delete token.json.
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'];

const CREDENTIALS_PATH = 'C:\\Development\\FreeLance\\GoogleSamples\\Credentials\\ServiceAccountCred.json';

/**
 * Load or request or authorization to call APIs.
 *
 */
async function authorize() {
    let client =  new google.auth.GoogleAuth({keyFile: CREDENTIALS_PATH, scopes: SCOPES});
    return client
}

/**
 * Lists the next 10 events on a public holiday calendar.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
async function listEvents(auth) {
    const calendar = google.calendar({version: 'v3', auth});
    const res = await calendar.events.list({
        calendarId: 'en.danish#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com',
        timeMin: new Date().toISOString(),
        maxResults: 10,
        singleEvents: true,
        orderBy: 'startTime',
    });
    const events = res.data.items;
    if (!events || events.length === 0) {
        console.log('No upcoming events found.');
        return;
    }
    console.log('Upcoming 10 events:');
    events.map((event, i) => {
        const start = event.start.dateTime || event.start.date;
        console.log(`${start} - ${event.summary}`);
    });
}

authorize().then(listEvents).catch(console.error);
```

Comment: And you are missing the imports. Could you please update your code?

Comment: See if that doesnt help