# how to read an external public shared calendar via google api

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, service-accounts, deno, google-api-nodejs-client

I have the following basic code to read some calendar events. The calendar is publicly shared from a normal private google user.

To use google api, I set up a service account with owner role, just to make things simple at first.
By using https://deno.land/x/google_deno_integration I try to make sure I'm using OAuth2, and according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47502537/2192829) access is possible

```
import { GoogleAPI } from "https://deno.land/x/google_deno_integration/mod.ts";


const serviceAccountConfig = await Deno.readTextFile(Deno.env.get('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'));
const credentials = JSON.parse(serviceAccountConfig);

const cal_id =  'my-cal-id';

const api = new GoogleAPI({
    email: "test-cal@gmadrid-natacion-f5fcd.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    scope: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events"],
    key: credentials.private_key,
});

const calget = await api.get(`https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/${cal_id}`);
console.log(calget);
```

Unfortunately, this is the answer I get:

```
$ deno run --allow-env --allow-read --allow-net index.2.ts
{
  error: {
    code: 403,
    message: "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
    errors: [
      {
        message: "Insufficient Permission",
        domain: "global",
        reason: "insufficientPermissions"
      }
    ],
    status: "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    details: [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        reason: "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT",
        domain: "googleapis.com",
        metadata: {
          service: "calendar-json.googleapis.com",
          method: "calendar.v3.Calendars.Get"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I don't know if I'm settings my service account badly (first hour user of google cloud here), if what I'm doing is possible, or if it's something wrong I'm not considering.

Comment: Im going to ask the same question I asked you in your question yesterday [why a service account can't access a public shared calendar for listing events?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77482955/1841839)  Why not just use an API key why do you want to use a service account?

Comment: If you are not using the Google api nodejs client library could you remove that tag.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it you can use a service account to read a public calendars.  The key to this is it must be public. Which means you are only going to have read only access to it.

In the below example. I am reading from the Danish holiday calendar.

```
// npm install googleapis@105 @google-cloud/local-auth@2.1.0 --save
// npm install googleapis

const {google} = require('googleapis');

// If modifying these scopes, delete token.json.
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'];

const CREDENTIALS_PATH = 'C:\\Development\\FreeLance\\GoogleSamples\\Credentials\\ServiceAccountCred.json';

/**
 * Load or request or authorization to call APIs.
 *
 */
async function authorize() {
    let client =  new google.auth.GoogleAuth({keyFile: CREDENTIALS_PATH, scopes: SCOPES});
    return client
}

/**
 * Lists the next 10 events on a public holiday calendar.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
async function listEvents(auth) {
    const calendar = google.calendar({version: 'v3', auth});
    const res = await calendar.events.list({
        calendarId: 'en.danish#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com',
        timeMin: new Date().toISOString(),
        maxResults: 10,
        singleEvents: true,
        orderBy: 'startTime',
    });
    const events = res.data.items;
    if (!events || events.length === 0) {
        console.log('No upcoming events found.');
        return;
    }
    console.log('Upcoming 10 events:');
    events.map((event, i) => {
        const start = event.start.dateTime || event.start.date;
        console.log(`${start} - ${event.summary}`);
    });
}

authorize().then(listEvents).catch(console.error);
```

I really don't know why you would want to when you can use just use an API key and get the same result

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const API_KEY = "[REDACTED]"

/**
 * Lists the next 10 events on a public holiday calendar.
 */
async function listEvents() {
    const calendar = google.calendar({version: 'v3', auth: API_KEY});
    const res = await calendar.events.list({
        calendarId: 'en.danish#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com',
        timeMin: new Date().toISOString(),
        maxResults: 10,
        singleEvents: true,
        orderBy: 'startTime',
    });
    const events = res.data.items;
    if (!events || events.length === 0) {
        console.log('No upcoming events found.');
        return;
    }
    console.log('Upcoming 10 events:');
    events.map((event, i) => {
        const start = event.start.dateTime || event.start.date;
        console.log(`${start} - ${event.summary}`);
    });
}

listEvents().catch(console.error);
```

## Deno

If you check the doc you linked [google_deno_integration](https://deno.land/x/google_deno_integration@v1.1) it clearly states Google Integration and Authentication for Deno.  This is not the same as authorization which is what you need.

There for I dont think that function will work.

If you are willing to use an api key then you just need to do a http get. Which appears to be possible using [fetch](https://deno.land/api@v1.38.1?s=fetch)

The url format is

> GET [https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/[calendarId]/events?key=[APIKEY]](https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/%5BcalendarId%5D/events?key=%5BAPIKEY%5D)

So using the example above for the Danish holiday calendar you have

```
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/en.danish%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/events?key=[APIKEY]
```

or

```
const response = await fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/en.danish%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/events?key=[APIKEY]");
console.log(response.status);  // e.g. 200
console.log(response.statusText); // e.g. "OK"
const jsonData = await response.json();
```

Comment: no problem with using an api_key in place of a service account. the point is: I'm using deno, as you can see in both the example and the tag, and the library you are using is not working. The library I'm trying to use, as far as I see, does not allow api keys, only service accounts. I've just tried with the danish calendar, but I got the same result: permission denied

Comment: While Deno has made great progress toward compatibility with code that uses Node.js APIs and conventions, there are still many cases where interop is not possible — the question is tagged with [tag:deno], not [tag:node.js].

Comment: @jsejcksn the question is tagged with [google-api-nodejs-client] which is the official google client library for node js.  Which is why I created the example using that.   I am not familiar with Deno but always up for a challenge.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77484833/how-to-read-an-external-public-shared-calendar-via-google-api/77486782?noredirect=1#comment136617052_77486782) @LindaLawton-DaImTo Understood.

Comment: There converted it to Deno